# I have a JSON object in my Controller (Ruby/Rails) but i want to access the Json's Object attributes. How to do that

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'openssl'

class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @json_object = JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(open("some link").read))
  end
end
```

This is my controller file

I have created a view to display the contents of the JSON object.

`show.html.erb`

```
<% = @json_object %>
```

It prints the JSON object
but

1) I want to print the JSON object in particular format.

2) i want to save certain JSON values in database.

Comment: `I want to print the JSON object in particular format`- can you be more specific on this?

Comment: particular format means
the proper indentation of a JSON object

Answer (score 1):

A JSON object in ruby is simply a `Hash` or `Array` of `Array`s, `Hash`es, `String`s and `Numeric`s.

So, to get to a specific element in your json, you should simply find it as the structure of the JSON suggests:

```
json_string = '{ "test": { "this": "here" }, "other": 3 }'

@json_object = JSON.parse(json_string)

@json_object['test']['this']
# => "here"
```

To print it as a JSON object again, you need to format it using `JSON.pretty_generate`:

```
JSON.pretty_generate(@json_object['test'])
# => {
# =>   "this": "here"
# => }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but i parsed the  string as
@json_object[1] 
this prints the whole array json object but i cannot access the internal elements.
eg of the JSON object.
puts json_object[1]
{"id"=>"325", "name"=>"Day Pass", "price_per_cycle"=>"0.0"}

Comment: @user3382377 I'm not sure what is the problem you have encountered - is it the formatting? See my update to the answer. Is it something else? What did you try? What did you get? What did you expect?